# How do I query based on values in multiple columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do I list all (unique) `ID`'s from the below table that have an `F` in `INSTRUCTION` for `TYPE` `PA` unless `CA` also has an `F` in `INSTRUCTION`

| ID | TYPE | INSTRUCTION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | CA | 203 |
| 12 | LT | F |
| 12 | PA | 408 |
| 15 | CA | F |
| 15 | LT | F |
| 15 | PA | F |
| 24 | CA | 608 |
| 24 | LT | 309 |
| 24 | PA | 75 |
| 133 | CA | 468 |
| 133 | LT | F |
| 133 | PA | F |

I tried the following
`WHERE table.TYPE)="PA") AND (table.INSTRUCTION)="F")`
But this also includes records having `INSTRUCTION` `F` for `TYPE` `CA` (which I don't want in the results)

| ID |
| --- |
| 15 |
| 133 |

The desired outcome is as follows:

| ID |
| --- |
| 133 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a query which selects 'PA' type and 'F' instruction rows.  Then left join that to a subquery which selects 'CA' type and 'F' instruction rows. And, in the main query, limit the selected rows to those where the subquery id is Null.

```sql
SELECT y.ID
FROM
    YourTable AS y
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT y2.ID
        FROM YourTable AS y2
        WHERE
                y2.TYPE='CA'
            AND y2.INSTRUCTION='F'
    ) AS sub
    ON y.ID = sub.ID
WHERE
        y.TYPE='PA'
    AND y.INSTRUCTION='F'
    AND sub.ID Is Null;
```